# Laravel custom post routes not working on live server?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have uploaded the laravel website on cpanel. Every thing is working fine but the custom post routes are not working properly. The same routes are working fine on local server but are not working on live server.

```
Route::resource('frontimages','FrontImagesController');   //working

Route::post('allumni_edit_current','AllumnisController@UpdateData');//not working
```

I know code is fine as it is working on localhost but it doesn't do any thing on live serve. Please help

Comment: what error do u get screenshot and send

Comment: dd($request->all());

Comment: and also dd(Alumni::where('id',$request->input('id'));

Comment: No error is shown. It shows update successful without error but no data is changed.

Comment: The same code works properly on local host but not on live server.

Comment: just dd those and do add ->first() to the where clause

Comment: All update functions on website are not updating data without showing error.

Comment: I have added first() but still not updating

Comment: Check if the database user you are using on live server have the permission to update or not

Comment: Yes user has the live permission ... I think the problem is with the post routes only. I have edited the question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the updated info instead of posting them in the comments. As it currently stands, you haven't given enough information for people to help without guessing. Try to debug a bit further and post back any new information.